# JDBC query + Scanner.next() gives InputMismatchException

Tags: java, jdbc, java.util.scanner

I have written the simplest implementation of DBMS using Java's JDBC. In my app I gve users ability to perform CRUD operations on some simple mysql database. Everything done in console. Problem is that when users chooses operation from menu (queries currently hardcoded) and then provides query a `java.util.InputMismatchException` exception is thrown. Any ideas why this might be happening ? Here's the code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base = new Base();
        boolean result = false;

        try{
            base.connect();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menuChoice = -1;
        String query = "";

        while(menuChoice != 0){
            showMenu();
            menuChoice = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please provide your query : ");

            switch(menuChoice){
                case 1: 
                        query = sc.next();
                        result = base.insert(query);
                        break;
                case 2: 
                        query = sc.next();
                        result = base.update(query);
                        break;
                case 3: 
                        query = sc.next();
                        result = base.retrieve(query);
                        break;
                case 4: 
                        query = sc.next();
                        result = base.delete(query);
                        break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Bye bye");
                    base.connection = null;
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void showMenu(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to simple JDBC example application./n");
        System.out.println("Choose desired operation:\n\n");
        System.out.println("1. Insert new instance");
        System.out.println("2. Update existing instance");
        System.out.println("3. Lookup");
        System.out.println("4. Delete instance");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");
        System.out.print("\n\n Select: ");
    }
}

class Base {
    private String username = "";
    private String password = "";
    private String dbname = "";
    private String servername = "";
    private Statement stmt = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    public Base(){
    }

    public boolean create(){
        return true;
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception{
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driverName);
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + servername + "/" + dbname;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
    }

    public boolean insert(String statement){
        try{
            int i=stmt.executeUpdate(statement);
            System.out.println("Successfully inserted.");
            return true;
        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println("Inserting data failed.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean update(String statement){
        try{
            int i=stmt.executeUpdate(statement);
            System.out.println("Successfully updated.");
            return true;
        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println("Updating data failed.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean retrieve(String query){
        try{
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Successfully retrieved :");
            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getRow()+". "+rs.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println("Updating data failed.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean delete(String statement){
        try{
            int i=stmt.executeUpdate(statement);
            System.out.println("Successfully deleted.");
            return true;
        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println("Deleting data failed.");
            return false;
        }
    }

}

/*

CREATE TABLE users (
user_login varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
user_password varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE groups (
group_id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
group_name varchar(50),
group_description varchar(200)
);

CREATE TABLE groups_users (
user_login varchar(10),
group_id varchar(10),
FOREIGN KEY (user_login) REFERENCES users(user_login),
FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups(group_id));


 */
```

---

EDIT: Traceback

```
Select: 1
Please provide your query : 
SELECT * FROM users
Inserting data failed.
Welcome to simple JDBC example application./n
Choose desired operation:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException


1. Insert new instance
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
2. Update existing instance
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
3. Lookup
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
4. Delete instance
0. Exit
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)


        at task.Main.main(Main.java:26)
 Select: Java Result: 1
```

so error comes from line `menuChoice = sc.nextInt();`. What more, when I've added another scanner instance just for queries, picking operation type returns user back to the menu without asking for query.

Comment: Please add the StackTrace for the error.

Comment: If the scanner is throwing that exception this is most probably totally unrelated to JDBC or the database access. Try to reduce your code to the part where the scanner throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the definition of [InputMismatchException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html):

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that
>   the token retrieved does not match the
>   pattern for the expected type, or that
>   the token is out of range for the
>   expected type.

I scanned through your code, and it seems like `menuChoice = sc.nextInt();` might be the one that throws that exception. Chances are your `while loop` is looping too many times and your scanner doesn't have the next int value to read, which is the reason you get this exception.

`nextInt()` is the only Scanner API you used that throws this particular exception. Here's the documentation of [nextInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29):-

```
public int nextInt(int radix)

Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.

If the next token matches the Integer regular expression defined above then the token is converted into an int value as if by removing all locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific suffixes, then mapping non-ASCII digits into ASCII digits via Character.digit, prepending a negative sign (-) if the locale specific negative prefixes and suffixes were present, and passing the resulting string to Integer.parseInt with the specified radix.

Parameters:
    radix - the radix used to interpret the token as an int value 
Returns:
    the int scanned from the input 
Throws:
    InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range 
    NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted 
    IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```

**EDIT:**

Try changing your while loop to be the following:-

```
while(menuChoice != 0 && sc.hasNext()){
   ...
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Scanner` breaks tokens on white space. `Scanner.next()` only returns one token (e.g. "SELECT"). The rest of your entered query is available for scanning for your `nextInt()` call, but the next token in your query (e.g. "*") is not an integer.

Instead of `next()` you probably want `nextLine()`.